# Windows API - Leer/Escribir del puerto Serie

Tags: c, windows, api, puertos

Estoy intentando enviar a un módulo 3G un comando AT cuya respuesta va a ser un OK. Quiero capturar ese OK en un buffer para su posterior tratado. Para ello hice lo siguiente:

1- Abri el puerto según:

```
hSerial = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

2- Configuré el puerto:

```
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)
```

3- Escribo en el puerto el comando AT correspondiente:

```
char At[] = "AT\r\n";
WriteFile(hSerial, At, length, &bytes_written, NULL)
```

4- Represento la respuesta por el terminal según:

```
ReadPort();
```

donde:

```
void ReadPort()
{
    char output[255];
    int i = 0;

    ReadFile(hSerial, output, sizeof(output), &bytes_read, NULL);
    if (bytes_read)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "* Start Read Port: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%c", output[i]);
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "* End Read Port: \n");
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, si en esa misma función le paso un buffer como parámetro, el resultado representado es diferente, es decir, el OK lo recibo a veces bien, otras veces solo la O, solo la K... sin ningún criterio. ¿Qué estaré haciendo mal? Lo que hago es:

```
char bufferRead[255];

ReadPort2(bufferRead);


void ReadPort2(char *output)
{

    int i = 0;

    ReadFile(hSerial, output, sizeof(output), &bytes_read, NULL);
    if (bytes_read)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "* Start Read Port: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%c", output[i]);
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "* End Read Port: \n");
    }
}
```

(Mi idea era tener el puntero a ese buffer accesible para hacer comprobaciones de lo que recibo.)

Muchas gracias!

Un saludo,

Comment: Por si acaso, aquú un tutorial sobre el puerto serie.
[https://www.slideshare.net/Metaconta2/arduino-c-y-puerto-serie](https://www.slideshare.net/Metaconta2/arduino-c-y-puerto-serie) Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedo comprobarlo, pero

```
ReadFile( hSerial, output, sizeof(output), &bytes_read, NULL );
```

Fíjate en ese `sizeof( output )`. **No** le estás pasando el tamaño del *buffer*, sino **el tamaño del tipo `char *`**.

Si sabes previamente el tamaño del buffer que estás usando, puedes indicarlo directamente; aunque te recomendaría cambiar la función a

```
void ReadPort2( char *output, size_t sz ) {
  int i = 0;

  ReadFile( hSerial, output, sz, &bytes_read, NULL );
  if ( bytes_read ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "* Start Read Port: \n" );

    for( i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++ ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%c", output[i] );
    }

    fprintf( stderr, "* End Read Port: \n" );
  }
}
```

Y llamarla en tu código así:

```
char bufferRead[255];

ReadPort2( bufferRead, sizeof( bufferRead ) );
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Le estaba dando vueltas y no veía el problema.

Gracias!!

Comment: @dcom Un placer :-)